# Several combination returned by bounded Knapsack algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, knapsack-problem

This task is similar to **bounded knapsack problem (BKP)**.
We have for about ~300 different meals with such parameters as: **ID, price, importance/rating, category**.

For example:

```
id  price  importance  type
-----------------------------
1   100     78         butter
2   50      89         milk
3   70      66         milk
4   66      50         butter
```

We want to select TOP-10 best combinations of products, but with specific configuration, we want to take only 3 kinds of butter, 2 types of bread and 2 types of milk. This TOP-10 combinations must have the highest sum of importance.
Also we must take in account the available budget.

It's a little bit differs from knapsack problems, because here we want TOP-10 results, not only the best.
And each meal/product of the same group (e.g butter) have different price and importance/rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that prices are integer and rather small, and you are thinking about some school-type DP solutions.

### DP in general

In dynamic programming algorithms, for each state we store only a single best partial solution. Usually we do not store the partial solution physically: only its cost and some simple backtracking information in order to reconstruct it later. We do not store other solutions for a state due to *optimal substructure* property: any partial solution with worse cost has continuations which are worse that the same continuations of the best partial solution.

In order to find *k* best solutions to the problem, you can simply store *k* best partial solutions for each state of DP. If for some state there are less than *k* solutions at all, then store all of them. Why can we drop a partial solution which is worse than *k* other partial solutions? Because any continuation of it would be worse than same continuations of those *k* better partial solutions.

Transitions in a forward-style DP are done as usual. When you consider some state, you should iterate over all of its *k* best partial solutions and try to continue each of them in all ways possible (e.g. take new item or not). For each continuation, look into its state. Insert the continuation into the sorted list of best partial solutions. If there are *k+1* partial solutions as the result, drop the worst one.

Most certainly you do not want to store partial solutions themselves in DP. Instead, store only total cost and backtracking information for each partial solution. Backtracking information should be enough to unambiguously determine the previous partial solution in DP. In such a way you can find best *k* solutions. It seems that DP solution with *k* best solutions takes *O(k)* times more memory and *O(k^2)* times more time (or *O(k log k)*) for knapsack, compared to finding only one best solution.

### Particular problem

It seems to me that you should solve your problem with a two-level algorithm:

1. Run a DP for bounded knapsack problem within each item category. As a result you'll obtain *k* best combinations of items of the category with each total cost (and with bounded number of items).
2. Find an optimal combination of solutions obtained on step 1. One solution must be taken from each of the categories considered.

For a single category, solving DP for choosing *s* items from list of *N* items with *W* knapsack size seems to take *O(s N W k^2)* time. Merging solutions from *c* categories in step 2 seems to take *O(c W^2 k^2)*, but it can be reduced to *O(c W k log(W k))* if balanced tree is used for merging.

Answer (score 1):

A heuristic approach which might be adequate is to use an evolutionary algorithm (which tend to be fairly easy to program for knapsack type problems) with a rather large population, let it evolve for a while, and just take the top 10 solutions.

Getting the provably top-10 solutions would of course be harder (literally -- it is clearly NP-hard). One approach would be to solve it to optimality, record the solution, add a constraint to rule out that solution, and then resolve. Do this repeatedly until you get the top 10 solutions.